# Magento 1.7.0.2 installation redirect loop index.php/install

Tags: php, apache, magento, redirect, installation

I've downloaded magento 1.7.0.2 and uploaded onto my WAMP server. I make sure that rewrite_module is enabled on Apache. 
But when I'm trying to run the installation, after the Configuration page where I entered database information and stuff, the server throws an infinite redirect loop.

I'm not sure if it's because of the rewrite engine or Virtual Host that I'm using on Apache.

Help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: What do the Apache error logs say?

Comment: Check `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` in you `php.ini`.

Comment: @james The Apache error log says nothing wrong...

Comment: @Zyava What should they be set?

Comment: Recommended value for `memory_limit` is 256MB for Magento. I usually set 512MB. ALso, try increase `max_execution_time` too 300 seconds. I always set these settings on every local PC where I install magento. Not sure it will help you but in my case infinite redirect had gone.

Comment: @Zyava: I've changed them, these two settings don't work...

Comment: Have the same issue. In my case I'm trying to install with nginx.

Comment: Why are there so many issues with Magento recently and no answers? What has happened beside Pay-Pal and E-Bay buying it???

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me too. I tried to install 1.7.0.2 with nginx and sample data from magento.

It seems that the problem is the sample data (or any other data in the magenta's database) according to http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/5182/#

Clearing the database and extracting the source code again fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The user that has privilleges on the database should be specified to have access on the localhost, not on all the hosts. For me it worked and I skipped the redirect loop.

Comment: it's not worked for me, I'm using root in DB on my dev for it